# Go to next element Recordset Access 2010 with vba

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access-2010, recordset

I need your help. I filtered a recordset with a query and looped through it to fill a list box.
Then I like to click on next and the next item with the specific values should with the text boxes, but I get an error message and the absolute position is -1.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnNextRecord_Click()
    Debug.Print "Move Next: " & m_rst.AbsolutePosition
    Do While Not m_rst.EOF
        m_rst.MoveNext
        Me.txtfield = m_rst("Value")
    Loop
End Sub
```

but it's not working!

Bets regards and thanks in advance

Matthias

Comment: which error code do you get? which line is highlighted? also: variable m_rst is not defined in your code. either it is global (is it?) or you didn't define it

Comment: the m_rst is global and it does not jump into the loop.. I don't know why

Comment: I get an Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)': The value you entered isn't valid for this field

Comment: Which line of code causes that error?

Comment: Also add the code that opens the recordset.

Comment: Sounds like the Recordset isn't ever initialized or is initialized with a query that returns no rows.

Comment: I think you may need to m_rst.movefirst to initialize the recordset

Comment: I found a solution:
Private Sub btnNextRecord_Click()
 me.ListRecordset.Selected(me.ListRecordset.ListIndes+2)=True
 ListRecordset_Click
End Sub